# PowerShell reading a list of text files in a folder

Tags: powershell

We need to get a list of workstation ids for a set of users.  We modified the startup script to run a batch file that dumps the info we need to a file share in the following method:

*username*.txt

Edit:  Here is a sample of the text file (there are 2000 users, so we will have 2000 files in time)

> ```
> Workstation1
> Workstation2
> CitrixServer1
> Workstation1
> Workstation1
> ```

We will have duplicates because they will login multiple times.

This file has the list of machines (workstation and citrix servers that the user has logged into).  Now I am trying to extract the information in a meaningful manner (there are over 1300 files  and the final count will be around 2000).  So far this is what I have:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
# this is the path for the share
$SearchFolder = "\\server\Users\*.txt" 

# Search each txt file in the path and store all of the lines and filenames that don't match the pattern

$File = Select-String -Path $SearchFolder -Pattern %CLIENTNAME%,"ECHO is on", "server*","vs*","ctx*"  -NotMatch | select line, filename 

$File
```

What this gives me is the following:

> ```
> Workstation1    User1
> Workstation2    User2
> Workstation3    User3
> Workstation4    User3
> Workstation4    User3
> ```

What I want to do is get a list of unique workstations that a user has logged in to.

> ```
> User1
> Workstation1   
>
> User2
> Workstation2   
>
> User3
> Workstation3   
> Workstation4
> ```

How can I do this?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could [edit] your question to include a sample of the content of `username.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output that you've stored in `$File` should already be an array of objects, each of which has a property called `.line` (which is the computer name) and a property called `.filename` (which is the user name).

By grouping them by user, you can get a list of workstations, and from there you can make that list unique:

```
$groups = $File | Group-Object filename
```

This gives you a new type of object, where the `.Name` property refers to the element being grouped by, in this case the filename (which is the user name). The `.Group` property is the original object(s).

So from there, you can iterate over the groups and get the workstations for each one:

```
$all = $groups | ForEach-Object {
    $user = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Name)
    $computers = $_.Group.line | Sort-Object | Select-Object -Unique
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        User = $user
        Computers = $computers
    }
}
```

Now `$all` will contain an array of objects, where each object represents a user, with an array of the computers. You can format that however you like.

#### Edit based on your comment:

> What I want is one column with users and the 2nd with workstations. If
>   a user has more than one workstation the the user name will be empty.

It's a bit strange, but I'd probably do something like this if you want a CSV that looks like that:

```
$groups | ForEach-Object {
    $user = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Name)
    $_.Group.line | Sort-Object | Select-Object -Unique | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            User = $user
            Computer = $_
        }
        $user = $null
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\workstationids.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks,   I added the following to cut the .txt extension from the users:
   <code> $all = $groups | ForEach-Object {
    $user = $_.Name
    $userwithoutextension = $user.Substring(0,$user.length-4)
    $computers = $_.Group.line | Sort-Object | Select-Object -Unique
    [PSCustomObject]@{
       # User = $user
        User = $userwithoutextension
        Computers = $computers
    }
} </code>

Comment: @JohnBalan I've edited to remove the extension. Doing it this way is cleaner I think.

Comment: Is there a way to pipe this to a csv?  Right now the output is:

username1  workstation1
username2  {workstation1,workstation2}

How can I pipe that to a CSV so it looks like:
Username1  workstation1
Username2  Workstation1
                     Workstation2

Comment: When I pipe like this:

$all | Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\workstationids.csv -NoTypeInformation

any user that has multiple workstations gets an entry like:  System.Object[]

Comment: @JohnBalan your original format is better for CSV, you have a one to many relationship like this, so what do you want when there is more than one workstation for a user? A column for each workstation? Or all workstations concatenated into some sort of string representation taking up one column?

Comment: What I want is one column with users and the 2nd with workstations.  If a user has more than one workstation the the user name will be empty. Something like this:
https://imgur.com/a/GsQAm

Where I only grab the unique workstations.

Comment: Adding this to the customobject:
Computers = $computers -join ','
outputs the workstations but they are comma seperated in the same row (problematic because some of the users are generic machine accounts that have a ton of logins)

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to get what you need using group-object, assuming the names of your colums are "user" and "machine" it would look something like

```
$files | group-object -property user
```